# Select columns containing array type and normal type with all flatten

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
i have a dataframe with these column. Column 1 and Column2 are array and rest of the columns are string I need to get the value of the both using select.
    +-----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
    |Column1    |    COLUMN2  |       NAME         |STATUS     |Sequence|
    +-----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
    |      [ABC]|        [ABC]|         BILAL AHMAD|       ID-N|       1|
    |      [ABC]|        [ABC]|        JUNAID Ali  |       ID-N|       1|
    |      [ABC]|        [ABC]|         BILAL ZAFAR|       ID-N|       1|
    |      [ABC]|        [ABC]|              KHALID|       ID-N|       1|
    |      [ABC]|        [ABC]|              KASHIF|       ID-N|       1|
    |      [ABC]|        [ABC]|              SALMAN|       ID-N|       2|
    +-----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
```

I have tried using below mentioned code. 
`df.select($"*")`

and

```
var seqCols = Seq("NAME","STATUS","sequence")

val allColumnsArr  =  "LEAD_CO_MNE" +: seqCols

df.select(colNames1.map(c=> col(c).getItem(0)):_* )
```

column1 and column2 are array so by using getItem(0) i will get the array 1st element. but this does not work for string columns. and the string columns are also dynamic like sometime they are as above some time string column name are like "DATE","AMOUNT","MODE"

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
|Column1    |    COLUMN2  |       NAME         |STATUS     |Sequence|
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
|      ABC  |        ABC  |         BILAL AHMAD|       ID-N|       1|
|      ABC  |        ABC  |        JUNAID Ali  |       ID-N|       1|
|      ABC  |        ABC  |         BILAL ZAFAR|       ID-N|       1|
|      ABC  |        ABC  |      KHALID|       ID-N|       1|
|      ABC  |        ABC  |      KASHIF|       ID-N|       1|
|      ABC  |        ABC  |              SALMAN|       ID-N|       2|
+-----------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------+
```

`"[]"` these bracket are removed from column1 and Column2 and now i have column1 and column2 as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column type can be checked, and if array - get first item:

```
val df = Seq(
  (Array("ABC"), Array("ABC"), "BILAL AHMAD", "ID-N", 1),
  (Array("ABC"), Array("ABC"), "JUNAID Ali", "ID-N", 1)
).toDF("Column1", "COLUMN2", "NAME", "STATUS", "Sequence")

val columnsToSelect = df.schema.map(c => if (c.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]) col(c.name).getItem(0).alias(c.name) else col(c.name))
df.select(columnsToSelect: _*)
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+------+--------+
|Column1|COLUMN2|NAME       |STATUS|Sequence|
+-------+-------+-----------+------+--------+
|ABC    |ABC    |BILAL AHMAD|ID-N  |1       |
|ABC    |ABC    |JUNAID Ali |ID-N  |1       |
+-------+-------+-----------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks you so much for your time pasha, with your solution my issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode the array Columns and select as usual

```
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  (Array("ABC"), Array("ABC"), "BILAL AHMAD", "ID-N", "1"),
  (Array("ABC"), Array("ABC"), "JUNAID Ali", "ID-N", "1"),
  (Array("ABC"), Array("ABC"), "BILAL ZAFAR", "ID-N", "1")
)).toDF("Column1", "COLUMN2", "NAME", "STATUS", "Sequence")
```

Explode the array type column or you could also select only first from the array here

```
val dfNew = df.schema.foldLeft(df) { (acc, schema) =>
  schema.dataType.typeName match {
    case "array" => acc.withColumn(schema.name, explode(col(schema.name)))
    case _ => acc
  }
}

dfNew.select("*").show(false)
```

Output :

```
+-------+-------+-----------+------+--------+
|Column1|COLUMN2|NAME       |STATUS|Sequence|
+-------+-------+-----------+------+--------+
|ABC    |ABC    |BILAL AHMAD|ID-N  |1       |
|ABC    |ABC    |JUNAID Ali |ID-N  |1       |
|ABC    |ABC    |BILAL ZAFAR|ID-N  |1       |
+-------+-------+-----------+------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you much for your time Shankar. let me try your solution.